# Why is it "einer meiner" twice and not "eins/eines" and "eine meine" given the gender of the nouns das Lied and die Band?

Tags: article, indefinite-pronoun

Given the sentence "That is one of my favorite songs, from one of my favorite bands.", and using "das Lied" instead of "der Song", both DeepL and Google Translate show:

- **English**: That is one of my favorite songs, from one of my favorite bands.
- **German (translation)**: Das ist einer meiner Lieblingslieder von einer meiner Lieblingsbands.

I thought the rule was that you use the form of "one" that matches the *singular* form of the target noun that is in plural, in this case *das Lied/die Lieder* and "die Band/die Bänder", as this Reddit post says:

https://www.reddit.com/r/German/comments/6ineu9/one_of_these/

Given that Linguee shows "Lied" as neuter and "Band" as feminine:

- https://www.linguee.com/german-english/translation/Lied.html
- https://www.linguee.com/german-english/translation/Band.html

Why isn't it "eines/eins meines LieblingsLieder" and "eine meine Lieblingsband" instead of "einer meiner" being used with both noun phrases as shown by DeepL and Google Translate?  Also, why isn't it "Lieblingsbände" instead of "Lieblingsbands" since *die Bände* is the plural form of "die Band"?

Comment: If you save the rule that "favorite song" should be translated as "Lieblingslieder" and re-run DeepL on the original input, you'll get the correct answer of "Dies ist eines meiner Lieblingslieder, von einer meiner Lieblingsbands."

Answer (score 5):

You are completely right that *Lied* is neuter and *Band* is feminine, so "eines" and "eine" are in fact correct. Since "songs" and "bands" are also used in plural form in German, the plural possessive pronoun "meiner" is correct in both sentences.

So, the translations should be *eines meiner Lieblingslieder* and *eine meiner Lieblingsbands*.

Comment: A small nitpick on terminology, but I think it's more logical to call *meiner* a possessive determiner here since to goes in front of a noun and replaces an article. There are possessive pronouns as well, and in German they are usually the same words, but for masculine nouns in the nominative case the determiner is *mein* while the pronoun is *meiner*. I don't know they handle this distinction in German grammars; it's more important in English because the words are usually different there. Welcome SE by the way; 3 upvotes on your first answer is impressive.

Comment: @RDBury: In German grammars, there is usually no distinction between possessive determiners and possessive pronouns. They are all usually called possessive pronouns.

Comment: @mach: Thanks. The determiners and the pronouns are declined slightly differently in German, so I think it's still important for learners to know which is which. The distinctions is probably less important for native speakers though since they already know how to decline everything.

Answer (score 4):

DeepL translates correctly to

> Das ist einer meiner Lieblingssongs...

(and "der Song" is male in German)

Google indeed has it wrong with

> <s>Das ist einer meiner Lieblingslieder</s>...

which is obviously wrong because "Lied" is neuter as you rightly say.

With respect to "Band", that's a bit of a tricky one:

There are actually three different "Band" words in German:

1. **der** Band (m) - tome or volume (book)
2. **das** Band (n) - ribbon or tape
3. **die** Band (f) - band (music), loan word from English and pronounced as such

Google Translate apparently can't tell the three apart.

The proper translation for the example sentence is thus

> Das ist eines meiner Lieblingslieder von einer meiner Lieblingsbands.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple issues in the question to address separately:

#### The correct form

The only correct sentence is:

> Das ist eine**s**  (nom. sg. n) meiner Lieblingslieder (gen. pl. n) von einer (dat. sg. f) meiner Lieblingsbands (gen. pl. f).

With *Lieblingssongs*, it would be:

> Das ist eine**r**  (nom. sg. m) meiner Lieblingssongs (gen. pl. m) von einer (dat. sg. f) meiner Lieblingsbands (gen. pl. f).

#### Why isn't it *eines meines* or *eine meine*?

Because *einer/eine/eines* (indefinite pronoun) and *meiner* (possesive determiner, i.e. 'article' of the following noun) do **not have the same case**.

*Einer/eine/eines* acts like a noun itself and takes the case and number according to its role in the sentence, while *meiner* is dependent and congruent to its noun. (I guess you were expecting that they would both depend on the noun and hence would have the same case and number as well as the same ending.)

However, because of their *semantical* relationship, *einer/eine/eines* and the noun do have the same *gender*.

- The first pronoun *eines* is the head of the nominal phrase in the complex predicate with *sein*. Thus, it is **nominative singular**. It has the meaning of *one* in English. It matches *die Lieblingslieder* (n. pl; sg.: *das Lied*) in being **neuter**, or, respectively, *die Lieblingssongs* (m. pl; sg.: *der Song*) in being **masculine**.
- The case of the second pronoun *einer* is governed by the preposition *von* and thus **dative singular**. It matches *die Bands* (f. pl.; sg.: *die Band*) in being **feminine**.
- The phrases *meiner Lieblingslieder* and *meiner Lieblingsbands* are **genitive plural**. The genitive has the same meaning as the preposition *of* in English (*one **of** my favourite …*). In plural, all genders have the same endings; nevertheless *meiner Lieblingslieder* is neuter and *meiner Lieblingsbands* is feminine.

#### Why isn't it *die Lieblingsbände(r)*?

Because the plural of ***die** Band* is *die Band**s***. This was already answered extensively by [tofro](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/64793/39389). *Der Band* and *das Band* on the one hand and *die Band* on the other are [homographs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homograph) in nominative singular, but they are inclined and pronounced differently:

- *Der Band* ('volume', pl. *die Bände*) and *das Band* ('ribbon', pl. *die Bänder*) are actually spoken differently in singular and plural. In singular, their root features an [a], while the plural is marked by the umlaut [​ɛ] (similiar to Engl. *man* – *men*).
- *Die Band* ('band', pl. *die Bands*), however, is a loanword; the orthography and pronounciation was adopted from English. Thus, it already has the umlaut [ɛ] in the singular root which is not marked orthographically. This means: the [ɛ] doesn't mark the plural and there would be no point to writing it with <ä> only in plural (that makes it different from *man* – *men* or *Mutter* – *Mütter* where the umlaut is the (only) plural marker and also reflected orthographically). Furthermore, *-er* is an untypical feminine plural ending (*die Mütter*, f. pl., being one notable exception).

Answer (score 1):

You're right, it has to be "Das ist **eines** meiner Lieblingslieder von einer meiner Lieblingsbands.". However, as you said, you changed "Song" into "Lied", which might be the reason. "Song" is masculine, therefore the sentence with "Das ist einer meiner Lieblingssongs" would be correct. However, "Lied" is neuter, and therefore "eines meiner Lieblingslieder" is correct.
I assume that this is an error in the translationservices you mentioned.

To your second question: The plural of "Die Band" is indeed "Die Bands", as [dwds](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Band#3) shows. "Bänder" is the plural of "Das Band", which means (among multiple translations) "strap".

Comment: The statement "*Bänder" is the plural of "[d]as Band"* is right, but the question was about *die Bänd**e*** (without *-r* in the end) which is the plural of ***der** Band* (meaning *volume*).

Comment: @amadeusamadeus: Actually, the question mentions *both* "die Bänder" and "die Bände".

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I see, I was only referring to the last sentence with the explicit question *why isn't it "Lieblingsbände" instead of "Lieblingsbands" since die Bände is the plural form of "die Band"?* for completeness.